# We don't have an SSL site and will be unable to get one. How do I work around this?

Tags: facebook, ssl, tabs, ssl-certificate

My organization has created a Facebook tab but because our site is not SSL certified the tab only works on some computers. We will not be getting SSL certified any time soon. Is there a way to work around this?

Comment: You can either add your self-signed cert's 'CA' to all the browser hitting the app, or you get a real cert.

Answer (score 3):

Your question can be paraphrased as 'how can we show HTTPS content to our users without needing to serve HTTPS content' - it's not possible

It shouldn't be difficult to buy a certificate for your domain and install it to the server - costs $15-$100 for the cert depending on where you get it and a few minutes (or hours, i guess) to reconfigure a web server

Obviously if you've a complicated setup with firewalls and strict procedures and processes in the company this will take a lot longer than the few minutes it would take a single developer, but surely in that case not supporting SSL is also seen as a big problem since you'll lose a relatively large percentage of users 
(source: It was >10% of users [about a year ago](http://www.quora.com/What-portion-of-Facebook-users-use-HTTPS) - it's higher now.)